# Compute the integral $ \ \int_X d \omega \ $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Compute the integral $\int_X d\omega,$
where $ \ \omega \ $ is a $1$-form on $X$ and $X$ is a $2$-segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as follows:
$$ \omega=[e^{xz}+2y e^{x^2+y^2}] \, dx + [\ln (2+z)+3xe^{x^2+y^2}] \, dy+3x^2y \, dz$$
and 
$X:E \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $X(r, \theta) = (r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta, 1-r^2)$ with $(r, \theta) \in [0,1] \times [0, 2\pi].$

**Answer:**

We can  use the Stoke's theorem as given below:
$$\int_X d\omega=\int_{\partial X} \omega,$$
where $\partial X$ is just the unit circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$ in the $xy$-plane ($z=0$).

Thus the above integral becomes 
$$ \int_{\partial X} \omega = \int_{\partial X} (1+2y) \, dx + (3x+\ln 2) \, dy,$$
since $z=0$ and $x^2+y^2=1.$

**Am I right so far?**

Comment: Any confirmation of my work?

Comment: Remember that $e^1 = e$, not $1$. Yes, this is correct. You do have to think about orientations, however. Now, what's the easiest way to do this line integral?

Comment: I used next $ \ x=\cos \theta , y=\sin \theta \ $  and integrate from $ \ 0 \to 2 \pi \ $. Is it true?  If not then do something

Comment: Use Stokes's Theorem again in a more obvious way to compute the line integral.

Comment: "obvious" way means? I need to some calculation help

Comment: That circle bounds a disk in the plane.

Comment: Sir I can not proceed? would you help me answering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\partial X$ we have $\omega = (1+2ey)dx + (\ln 2 + 3ex)dy$. Note that if we set $D = \{(x,y,0): x^2+y^2\le 1\}$, oriented upwards (as, presumably, $X$ is oriented upwards, coming from the canonical orientation on $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$), then $\partial D = \partial X$ and
$$\int_{\partial X}\omega = \int_{\partial D}\omega = \int_D d\omega = \int_D e\,dx\wedge dy = e\,\text{area}(D) = \pi e.$$

This same principle applies whenever we have oriented manifolds with boundary: If $\partial M = \partial N$, then $\int_M \omega = \int_N \omega$ for any exact form $\omega$.

Comment: I got the same result. thanks a lot